# How do I add multiple shapes to one skeleton

Tags: armature

Using Avastar, how do i add multiple second life shapes to one skeleton as displayed in this video [Creating "Standard" sizes for the Second Life avatar using Blender's Shapekeys](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nuubb5C64Ck)

Answer (score 0):

Exactly the same as attaching one shape to a skeleton. Make sure all the shapes are selected, then select the skeleton (i.e. make sure the skeleton is the active, more brightly outlined object). Then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to mark the skeleton as parent of the shapes.

Comment: I should have mentioned that i also work with Avastar and for some reason it doesn't allow me to load in multiple shapes, it swaps the shapes in stead of letting me add them up..

Comment: What is Avastar? If you have problems with an add-on, ask the author of the add-on.

Comment: It's an add-on designed for rigging Second Life shapes